# Open Resource window in eclipse shows pyc files

Tags: eclipse, pydev

In eclipse the Open Resource window (Hot keyed to Cmd+Shift+R) to open a file by typing its name seems to show *.pyc files despite the Navigator view correctly hiding them.

Is there anyway to set this up to ignore PYC files?

I have looked at the following links and it appears that pydev may require a src folder underneath the main eclipse folder. I do not have that structure however the full project has been marked as a 'source' folder in Pydev - PYTHONPATH under project properties.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pydev/forums/forum/293649/topic/2183420
http://pydev.org/manual_101_project_conf2.html

Answer (score 33):

I found the solution!

CMD+i on the project folder (or "right click" -> properties), then:

under "resources" -> "resources filters":

- click "add"
- choose "exclude all"
- select "files and folders"
- check "all children (recursive)"
- type ***.pyc** in the text field at the bottom
- ok
- ok

\o/

Comment: Is there any way to do this by default? Or on more than one project at a time?

Comment: I switched to PyCharm... it's definitely a better IDE :D

Comment: If anyone is looking for a similar solution for Java, be careful: excluding `*.class` files [may break](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23101136/320036) inter-project references.

Comment: Do this for `__pycache__` folders while you're at at it...